# Best practice to initialize List ? Autowire List or Contructor Initialization?

Tags: spring, list, spring-mvc

Hi i need to know the best practices to initialize list,
this is what am doing now...

```
    @Autowired
    private List<User> userList;
```

Other option is to initialize through constructor.

```
    private List<User> userList;


    public UserDaoImpl() {

        userList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

These implementations have been made in my Dao classes,
what is the best practice i should follow ?

p.s. i have simplified the code to have more focus on the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first option.
If userList is not able to get autowired it will fail anyway.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer with memory management in consideration ? i also notice that the first method does not allow the list to have a polymorphic behavior ( Eg - Not allowing the list to have an implementation of ArrayList )

Comment: You can inject every implementation you want.
Check out:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injecting-collections